# Given the graph of a relation R on a set of real numbers, how can you visually determine if R has the reflexive, anti/symmetric properties?

Tags: functions, logic

Answers:

a. It must contain all points on the line $y=x$ where $x$ is in the domain of the relation. From a
point on the graph, move vertically to the line $y = x$ and that point must be on the graph.

b. If $(a,b)$ is on the graph, its reflection about the line $y = x$ must also be on the graph.

c. If $(a,b)$ is on the graph and $a \neq b$, then the reflection of $(a,b)$ about the line $y = x$
cannot be on the graph.

Please, elaborate on these answers. I have no idea what they mean.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

R(a,b) is a set of pairs with the properties :

R is reflexive

R(a,a) is in the set for all real a. This means, that any point (a,a) is in the set, so every point of the line y=x (which is of the form (a/a)) must be in the graph.

If R is symmetric, we have

R(a,b) is in the set implies that R(b,a) is in the set. But the point (b/a) is the
reflection of the point (a/b) on the line y=x.

If R is antisymmetric, we have

R(a,b) is in the set implies that R(b,a) is not in the set. So if a graph contains a point (a/b), it cannot conatin the reflection point (b/a).